# Find a value in one row, and then extract a value in another row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried several examples but I'm a bit stuck on this!
On sheet1 I have a column which is generated by a formula in column C. In column D I want to be able to populate with associated value on sheet2

Sheet1:

```
      C       D
3   Text1
4   Text4
5   Text2
6   Text3
```

Sheet2:

```
     C         E         G       I
...
4  Val1      Val2      Val4     Val3
5
6  Text1     Text4     Text2    Text3
```

Result Needed:

```
    C         D
3   Text1    Val1
4   Text4    Val2
5   Text2    Val4
6   Text3    Val3
```

I have tried using HLookup but I only seem to get N/A error when using an exact match, I wonder if this is to do with the values in column C being generated by a formula?
Is there something obvious I am missing?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$4:$4,MATCH(C3,Sheet2!$6:$6,0))
```